# Python and matrix of objects

Tags: python, matrix

I'm new to Python. I use version 3.3. I'm doing something wrong but I can't find.
I create tb1, an array of objects. 
Content is initialized and then printed.
I create tb2, a second array. 
The content of tb1 is then copied into tb2 while transposing rows and columns.
A second print shows that tb1 is altered. I can't understand why.
The problem do not happen with a matrix of integers.
Results of prints are:

123456789

123256369

```
#!/bin/python3
class Item:
  n=0
  m=0

class Tb:
  items = [[Item() for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]

tb1 = Tb()
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(3):
    tb1.items[i][j].n = i*3+j+1

# print original content of tb1
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(3):
    print( tb1.items[i][j].n, end="")
print()

tb2 = Tb()
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(3):
    tb2.items[j][i].n = tb1.items[i][j].n

# print content of tb1. It is altered
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(3):
    print( tb1.items[i][j].n, end="")
print()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Tb:
    items = [[Item() for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
```

Here you are creating a class variable `items` that will be shared by all instances of Tb. To create instance variables, use `__init__`:

```
class Tb:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = [[Item() for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
```

Comment: For the record, the definition of `Item` should change similarly. It just happens to work because the instance-level `n` is shadowing the class-level variable, but `m` will still be shared across instances.